# Static List of Objects occasionally resets in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I ran into a strange issue recently. Inside my MVC application, under "Application_Start" I initialize a couple of hooks, one of those hooks creates a static List of objects that I later on apply/use throughout the application.

The application is never terminated or reset unless we need to, but occasionally my list of objects will have nothing stored on it after some time; hence it is being reset/cleared somehow.

Is there a solution to this issue? Is there an explanation to why this is occurring?

Hooks Class:

```
 public class Hooks
 {
    public static List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
 }
```

I am just using this list through the application.

**EDIT:**
I did some more research and it looks like IIS clears all static variables when it resets the pool. Does anyone know a possible solution to hold state of this object even after IIS clears these variables?

Comment: Please provide more details. What framework you use, on which environment does this happen, on what hosting, on debug/release...

Comment: Some code would be nice as well. Do you write to the list sometimes?

Comment: I do write to the list, but like I stated it loses the object at random. I can provide some code, I will edit the post.

Comment: I found it very similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958214/reset-static-variables-in-iis

But nobody had a valid solution for this.

Comment: I did some more research and it looks like IIS clears all static variables when it resets the pool. Does anyone know a possible solution to hold state of this object even after IIS clears these variables?